# How does one calculate LD50 from a glmer?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am analyzing a data set where ~10 individuals are exposed to a set treatment (Time) and mortality is recorded (Alive, Dead). `glmer` was used to model the data because Treatments were blocked (Trial).
From the following model I want to predict the Time at which 50% of individuals die.

```
Trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
Time <- c(2, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 39)
Alive <- c(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 8, 1, 0, 0, 4, 6, 1, 2, 0)
Dead <- c(0, 10, 6, 10, 10, 10, 7, 10, 0, 8, 1, 9, 10, 10, 5, 0, 8, 6, 10)
ostrinaA.glmm<- glmer(cbind(Alive, Dead)~Time+(1|Trial), family = binomial(link="logit"))
summary(ostrinaA.glmm)
```

If I was simply modelling using `glm`the `dose.p` function from `MASS` could be used. From a different forum I found generalized code for a dose.p.glmm from [Bill Pikounis](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-January/224123.html). It is as follows:

```
      dose.p.glmm <-  function(obj, cf = 1:2, p = 0.5) {
      eta <- obj$family$linkfun(p)
      b <- fixef(obj)[cf]
      x.p <- (eta - b[1L])/b[2L]
      names(x.p) <- paste("p = ", format(p), ":", sep = "")
      pd <- -cbind(1, x.p)/b[2L]
        SE <- sqrt(((pd %*% vcov(obj)[cf, cf]) * pd) %*% c(1, 1))
      res <- structure(x.p, SE = SE, p = p)
      class(res) <- "glm.dose"
      res
    }
```

I'm new to coding and need help adjusting this code for my model. My attempt is as follows:

```
dose.p.glmm <-  function(ostrinaA.glmm, cf = 1:2, p = 0.5) {
  eta <- ostrinaA.glmm$family$linkfun(p)
  b <- fixef(ostrinaA.glmm)[cf]
  x.p <- (eta - b[1L])/b[2L]
  names(x.p) <- paste("p = ", format(p), ":", sep = "")
  pd <- -cbind(1, x.p)/b[2L]
  SE <- sqrt(((pd %*% vcov(obj)[cf, cf]) * pd) %*% c(1, 1))
  res <- structure(x.p, SE = SE, p = p)
  class(res) <- "glm.dose"
  res
}
dose.p.glmm(ostrinaA.glmm, cf=1:2, p=0.5)
Error in ostrinaA.glmm$family : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Any assistance adjusting this code for my model would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance I would think replacing

```
eta <- obj$family$linkfun(p)
```

with

```
f <- family(obj)
eta <- f$linkfun(p)
```

should do the trick.

You also need to replace the `res <- ...` line with

```
res <- structure(x.p, SE = matrix(SE), p = p)
```

This is rather obscure, but is necessary because the `print.dose.glm` method (from the `MASS` package) automatically tries to `cbind()` some stuff together.  This fails if `SE` is a fancy matrix from the `Matrix` package rather than a vanilla matrix from base R: `matrix()` does the conversion.

If you are *very* new to coding, you might not realize that you don't have to change the `obj` variable name in the code you've copied to `ostrina.glmm`. In other words, Pikounis's code should work perfectly well with *only* the two modifications I suggested above.

Comment: Yes very new would be correct. Thanks for your quick answer but I'm still having problems. I've tried as you suggested and am now returning error code: Error: not-yet-implemented method for cbind2(<glm.dose>, <dgeMatrix>).
 ->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.